# Including a filter in my search, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, search, mysqli, filter

I've implemented a search bar into a site that will go to a database and fetch results from it, but now I want to add a filter to that search, so that you can filter by a set of categories (defined also in this database).
How can I fetch the parameters in the Filter Dropdown and pass them on to the PHP search?

so far, my html looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
         <span id="search_concept">Filtrar</span> <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <?php print("$salida");?>
            <li><a href="#" data-value="action">Todo</a></li>
         </ul>
         <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">         
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchinv" placeholder="Buscar" onkeydown="searchq();">
     </div>
   </div>
```

the javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
    var concept = $(this).text();
    $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
    $('.input-group #search_param').val(param);
    });
  });
function searchq(){
  var searchTxt = $("input[name='searchinv']").val();
  $.post("search.php",{searchVal: searchTxt}, function(output){
    $("#output").html(output);
  });
}
```

And the PHP:

```
  if(isset($_POST['searchVal'])){
$searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE name_product LIKE '%".$searchq."%'");

if($query->num_rows){
  $rows = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  forEach($rows as $row){
    $nprod = $row['name_product'];
    $id = $row['id_product'];
    $output .= '<div> '.$nprod.' '.$id.'</div>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Flagging as asking for a tutorial. You do not exhibit an issue, other than "I do not do X, but I want to start doing X'. While you provide code, there are no error messages to determine whether you actually tested your theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all the categories from the database and then loop through them in the view as options in a select. Like this:

```
<select id='search-filter' name='filter'>
<!--$categories is an array containing all your available filters-->
<?php foreach($categories as $category):?>
  <option value='<?php echo $category;?>'><?php echo $category;?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

That will create a dropdown with the filters as the options.

Then in your javascript edit the `searchq()` function so that it posts the value in the select field too:

```
function searchq(){
  var searchTxt = $("input[name='searchinv']").val();
  var filter = $('search-filter').val();
  $.post("search.php",{searchVal: searchTxt,filter:filter}, function(output){
    $("#output").html(output);
  });
}
```

In your php add the filter to your query. If all the filter values apply to the same column this is easy:

```
if(isset($_POST['searchVal'])){
  $searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
  if(isset($_POST['filter'])) {
    $filter = $_POST['filter'];
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE name_product LIKE '%{$searchq}%' AND filter_col = '{$filter}'");
  } else {
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE name_product LIKE '%{$searchq}%'");
  }
}
...
```

If the filters each apply to different columns then I would send them over as an array of key value pairs. Loop through that array append the the query the additional where clause. Something like this:

```
$filters = json_decode($_POST['filters']);//send the variable as a json encoded array
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE name_product LIKE '%{$searchq}%' ";
foreach($filters as $col=>$val) {
  $sql_query .= " AND {$col} = {$val} ";
}
$query = $mysqli->query($sql_query);
...
```

Of course if this is the case you'll need to save what column each filter applies to in the database, then print it as a data attribute on each select option, make multiple selects available in your select input, and in the javascript build and json encode the option to post to the backend.

On a side note - don't forget to escape your data on the backend to prevent sql injection: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Hope that helps and good luck!